# How to install from ubuntu installation Ubiquity skipped plugins and updates

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity

What packages are being installed with checking 1st and 2nd option?
How with one line install it all?

[image: Skipped]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Answer (score 1):

It install [Ubuntu restricted extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats). Recommend not to use it while installing as installation may freeze. Later install it from ubuntu software center.

Comment: how with one line install it all?

Comment: can't get your comment exactly. Does your question means- how a one line command install multiple software packages?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question "How with one line install it all" as "How do I install all of Ubuntu without having to select a bunch of options during the install". What you want in that case is something called an "unattended" install.

There is a guide here on how you can setup your own unattended installation of Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UnattendedCD

**edit** I just noticed that this link is fairly old, and there doesn't seem to be any guides that I can find of doing this on 12.04. Your best bet might be to actually install it on one computer first, and if other computers are similar you could simply clone the hdd and install an image directly on the other computers.